# Obtaining raw request body in JAX-RS resource method

Tags: java, http, rest, jax-rs

How can I access the raw request body from a JAX-RS resource method, as `java.io.InputStream` or `byte[]`? I want the container to bypass any `MessageBodyReader` for a specific resource class or method, but I have other resources in the projects which should be using some `MessageBodyReader`.

I have tried this, but it will invoke registered `MessageBodyReader`s and fail to assign the result to `InputStream` (same issue with `byte[]`).

```
@POST
public Response post(@Context HttpHeaders headers, InputStream requestBody) {
    MediaType contentType = headers.getMediaType();
    // ... 
}
```

I have also tried this, but then the container fails to initialize with this error:

```
SEVERE: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public javax.ws.rs.core.Response SomeResource.post(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) at parameter at index 0
SEVERE: Method, public javax.ws.rs.core.Response SomeResource.post(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest), annotated with POST of resource, class SomeResource, is not recognized as valid resource method.
```

```
@POST
public Response post(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
    String contentType = request.getContentType();
    InputStream requestBody = request.getInputStream();
    // ... 
}
```

The method is in a sub resource class, which is created from a method with a `@Path` annotation in another resource class.

I am using Jersey 1.11.

Comment: Your second error doesn't seem related to a `@Context` error. Do you have a class level `@Path` annotation?

Comment: No, but it is in fact a subresource, invoked from a method in another resource class with a @Path annotation. It does work if I remove the HttpServletRequest parameter (but then I won't get the body).

Answer (score 20):

just incase this helps anyone

```
public Response doAThing(@Context HttpServletRequest request, InputStream requestBody){


        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(requestBody));
        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            out.append(line);
        }
        System.out.println(out.toString());   //Prints the string content read from input stream
        reader.close();

        return Response.ok().entity("{\"Submit\": \"Success\"}").build();

    }
```

Answer (score 11):

This works for me:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.WILDCARD)
@Produces(MediaType.WILDCARD)
public Response doSomething(@Context HttpServletRequest request, byte[] input) {
    log.debug("Content-Type: {}", request.getContentType());
    log.debug("Preferred output: {}", request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the reason that injecting HttpServletRequest did not work, it's because I did run my code in Jersey Test Framework, not within a proper Servlet container. It works if I run it in a proper Servlet container.

It is a pity that there is no pure JAX-RS way of getting the raw request body.

Comment: Why is that not a pure jaxrs way?

Comment: @David Williams Because HttpServletRequest is part of servlet api, not jaxrs. And if you want to do integration test with low level jersey test container like the in-memory one, you won't be able to use servlet api.

Comment: I am now having the same issue as well!