# Read a list of parameters in order /1;2;3;4;5

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, dropwizard

Is it possible to read a parameter list like `example.com/1;2;3;4;5` in the same order as provided by the URL?

My current not working approach is:

```
public Response(@PathParam("list") PathSegment list) {
   Set<String> listParams = list.getMatrixParameters().keySet();
   List<String> listList = new ArrayList<>(list.size() + 1);

   listList.add(list.getPath());
   for (String param : list) {
      listList.add(param);
   }
}
```

It does work for `1;2;3;4;5`, but it does not work for `1;5;4;3;2`. In both cases the output would be `1;2;3;4;5`. The `matrixParameters` appear to be sorted alphabetically and not by the input order. Just reading the whole parameter as a String and parsing it manually would be fine, but couldn't find a way to do this either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, take a careful look at the [PathSegment documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/PathSegment.html#getMatrixParameters--).
The *matrix parameters* are stored in [MultivaluedMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap.html). Its only implementation is [MultivaluedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedHashMap.html). It does not preserve the order of the elements.

I've done a quick check how to get the raw request parameters in JAX-RS. There seems to be no pure JAX-RS way. You could try to work with the raw HttpServletRequest object as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149507/obtaining-raw-request-body-in-jax-rs-resource-method) to get the information.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up simply parsing the raw http request, as proposed by you.